# Django login error and cannot login

Tags: python, django, authentication

I try to find a similar question but I did not find the answer what I want. I am new to Django, I was trying to learn about authentication in Django but I got an error like this:

```
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.GET['username']
            password = request.GET['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                error = " Sorry! Username and Password didn't match, Please try again ! "
                return render(request, 'girl/login.html',{'error':error})
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'girl/login.html', {"form":form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password')
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Login</h1>
    {% if error %}
        {{ error }}
    {% endif %}
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if you are trying to learn Django internals or just to build an application but this is *not* the way to customize the login form. You can simply override the login template and not mess with the form/view code.

Comment: Please add full stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to inherit from `forms.Form` not `forms.ModelForm`,

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

Also, in your views, edit something like this,

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                error = " Sorry! Username and Password didn't match, Please try again ! "
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'girl/login.html', {"form":form})
```

Comment: It's working, but i got new error. the error is "
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "'username'""
Should i edit my view ???

Comment: mm... yeah. I'll post the corrected one in just a min.

Comment: You had checked if the `request.method` was `POST` but you were trying to access `request.GET`. I have changed that and please do check the function and if necessary let me know of anything.

Comment: @Scarlettstone if you are using forms, do not access `request.POST` use `form.cleaned_data`

Comment: It's Working! Thank you so much. Should i create a models for login ??

Answer (score 0):

You set password as a normal text. Try like this.

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            # normalized data
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('/')
            else:
                error = " Sorry! Username and Password didn't match, Please try again ! "
                return render(request, 'girl/login.html',{'error':error})
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'girl/login.html', {"form":form})
```

Comment: `authenticate()` method only returns user if the `username` and `password` are valid. Actually `set_password()` is redundant and unnecessary.

Comment: But if he does not user set_password(), isn't the password save as a normal test ?

Comment: Then, `authenticate()` method won't return a user instance. It would return None. The place where `set_password()` method to use is definitely not here. It should be where, user instances are created. I hope you got my point.